# Is it possible to have a single axiom that subsumes axioms 8-10 in this list?

Tags: first-order-logic, order-theory

Think of a totally ordered set as an “order-theoretic line”. Similarly, [cyclic orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order) are “order-theoretic circles”. I want to find the right axioms for an “order-theoretic plane”.

My ultimate goal is to design a data structure that represents a finite set of points on an “order-theoretic plane”, similarly to how binary search trees represent finite sets of points on an “order-theoretic line”.

I will describe the progress I made so far. I started with an axiomatization of oriented triangles:

> We postulate a relation $\triangle abc$ (triangle) satisfying the following axioms:
>
> 1. **Cyclicity:** $\triangle abc \iff \triangle cab$
> 2. **Asymmetry:** $\neg \triangle abc \vee \neg \triangle cba$
> 3. **Encirclement:** $\neg \triangle abc \vee \neg \triangle acd \vee \neg \triangle adb \vee \triangle bcd$

Encirclement is the ternary analogue of a partial order's transitive property. The transitive property of a partial order constructs a large oriented segment by concatenating two smaller ones (in the partial order's Hasse diagram). Similarly, the encirclement property of $\triangle$ constructs a large oriented triangle by concatenating three smaller ones.

Three pairwise distinct points $a,b,c$ are collinear if neither $\triangle abc$ nor $\triangle cba$ holds. If three points are collinear, exactly one of them must be between the other two:

> We postulate a relation $\overline {abc}$ (segment) satisfying the following axioms:
>
> 4. **Symmetry:** $\overline {abc} \iff \overline {cba}$
> 5. **Acyclicity:** $\neg \overline {abc} \vee \neg \overline {cab}$
>
> Triangles and segments satisfy the following axioms:
>
> 6. **Mutual exclusion:** $\neg \triangle abc \vee \neg \overline {abc}$
> 7. **Exhaustiveness:** $\triangle abc \vee \triangle cba \vee \overline {abc} \vee \overline {bca} \vee \overline {cab} \vee a = b \vee a = c \vee b = c$

This axiomatization is incomplete. I need to postulate that, if $\overline {abc}$, then $\triangle abd$, $\triangle acd$, $\triangle bcd$ are equivalent statements.

Alas, I have not found a neat way to translate this informal statement to formal language. I have to clumsily split it into three statements:

> 8. **Triangle base translation 1:** $\neg \overline {abc} \vee \neg \triangle abd \vee \triangle acd$
> 9. **Triangle base translation 2:** $\neg \overline {abc} \vee \neg \triangle acd \vee \triangle bcd$
> 10. **Triangle base translation 3:** $\neg \overline {abc} \vee \neg \triangle bcd \vee \triangle abd$

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Any axioms P, Q, R can be replaced by the single axiom:   P & Q & R.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Sure, but that would probably not be very convenient for performing actual calculations. It would destroy how nicely most of the axioms are written as disjunctions. (And the ones that aren't written as disjunctions are simple rewriting rules.)